# Can dpkg or apt be installed on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, apt, dpkg

I'm kinda curious. And if it is possible, then how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [`dpkg`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dpkg/) is an AUR package for a long time.  Yet, it is not meant to install `.deb` packages.  Instead it is meant to build `.deb` packages on Arch (i.e. packages that then can be installed on Debian, Mint, Ubuntu, etc).

On the other hand, installing a `.deb` package on Arch is not hard.  Let's take `slack` (a chat program that has a `.deb` package) as an example.  In the [PKGBUID](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=slack-desktop) of this AUR package you can see a simple script that performs the installation:

```
bsdtar -O -xf "slack-desktop-${pkgver}"*.deb data.tar.xz | bsdtar -C "$pkgdir" -xJf -

# Permission fix
find "${pkgdir}" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

# Remove all unnecessary stuff
rm -rf "${pkgdir}/etc"
rm -rf "${pkgdir}/usr/share/lintian"
rm -rf "${pkgdir}/usr/share/doc"

# Move license
install -dm755 ${pkgdir}/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}
mv ${pkgdir}/usr/lib/slack/LICENSE ${pkgdir}/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}
ln -s /usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}/LICENSE ${pkgdir}/usr/lib/slack/LICENSE
```

And yes, that is the best way to install `.deb` packages on Arch: converting them to AUR packages.

References:

- [Create packages for other distributions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages_for_other_distributions)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is not valid anymore.

`dpkg` package is not available in AUR anymore. It was moved to the main package repository: https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/dpkg/

Therefore it can now be installed with `pacman` as any other package:

```
sudo pacman -Syu dpkg
```